# Embedded resource image is adding a white dot to my image

Tags: c#, image, silverlight

I have a transparent .png that I'm loading from my assembly. I'm converting this embedded resource to a byte array then to a Bitmap Image, problem is there's always a white dot added to the image,

[image]

I'm using the following code,

```
        using (var stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.test.png"))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);

            return buffer;
        }
```

This image is straight from https://www.iconfinder.com/ with no modification, I've also tried other images, same effect.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just make into vector path data and omit all that other mess.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Build Action of the image file to `Resource` instead of `Embedded Resource` and then create a BitmapImage like this:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("MyProject.test.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

If you had a file `test.png` in an `Images` folder in your project, the Uri would look like this:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/test.png", UriKind.Relative));
```